# How can I place the torches in terraria?

Tags: terraria

Just got the new game and noticed it's tricky to place torches. I have placed a torch or two but I don't know what I did to place them. Is there an easier way to place the torches besides clicking a thousand times?

Answer (score 10):

You can place torches on blocks (floors and "walls") and actual wall-blocks. The easiest way to place a torch is to hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (default) and click near a block, either on its side or top of it, but make sure you don't click the block. If the background is *not* sky, rocky or hell, you can click anywhere on the background to place a torch.

Also make sure you're close enough, you can only place a torch (or a block) from 5 blocks away (horizontal) and 3 blocks away (vertical).

Comment: You can also only place a torch in a space up to 3 blocks away from your character in any direction, about the same distance as you can place any placeable block.

Comment: To easily distinguish between walls and background scenery, make sure parallax is set to _at least_ 30 in the video settings. This will make background scenery "scroll" slower than foreground (i.e. wall, block) tiles, making it easier to spot the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Torches can be placed adjacent to blocks or on background tiles.

Comment: Note that in the underground, the background tiles are not the type of tiles that can be edited. It's just background.